# My UIStackView components aren't horizontially aligned

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a horizontal stack view within a vertical one, and the elements in the horizontal one aren't aligning.

[image: like here]

vs

[image: how I want it to look]

this is what I tried so far

```
let subStackView = UIStackView()
    subStackView.axis = .horizontal
    subStackView.alignment = .trailing
    subStackView.distribution = .fill
    subStackView.spacing = 3
    subStackView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    subStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let clockImage = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Shape 8"))
    clockImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    
    let countdownLabel = UILabel()
    countdownLabel.formatteLabel(text: "12 س  35 د 12 ث", fontName: "Cairo-SemiBold", fontSize: 14)
    countdownLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.58, blue: 0.22, alpha: 1)
    subStackView.addArrangedSubview(clockImage)
    subStackView.addArrangedSubview(countdownLabel)
    
    rightStackView.addArrangedSubview(subStackView)
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what layout you want. Do you want the `clockImage` *vertically centered* with the label? Maybe add another image of how you ***want*** it to look.

Comment: I just want them to be horizontally aligned. I added a picture of how its supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing the terms "horizontal" and "vertical". Horizontal is across (left-to-right or right-to-left). Vertical is up-and-down.

When using `.axis = .horizontal` on a `UIStackView`, the `.alignment` property controls the **vertical** alignment.

The options are:

- `.top`
- `.center`
- `.bottom`
- `.firstBaseline`
- `.lastBaseline`

You *probably* want `.center`... try each of those options and see if you can get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `clockImage` in a view with constraint. For example:

```swift
let clockImage = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Shape 8"))
clockImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

let view = UIView()
view.addSubview(clockImage)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
     clockImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
     clockImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
     clockImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
     clockImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
])
```

Then, instead of `subStackView.addArrangedSubview(clockImage)` add `subStackView.addArrangedSubview(view)`

Comment: If you have the project in github, it'll be better :)